# Trop on the word וְעַם in Megillat Esther 4:11

Tags: megillat-esther, trop-cantillation

In [Esther 4:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.4.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the pasuk tells us כָּל־עַבְדֵ֣י הַמֶּ֡לֶךְ וְעַם־מְדִינ֨וֹת הַמֶּ֜לֶךְ. In different versions of the megillah, I have either seen no trop mark on the word וְעַם oir seen a telisha ketana. Which one is correct?

Comment: No Telisha is correct.

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you have a source for that?

Comment: A source? Do you want Esther and Mordechai's original mailing?? The overwhelming majority of older texts don't have that Telisha. There is no other data. (I suppose you could argue that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lectio_difficilior_potior applies here too.)

Comment: Personally I'm more concerned about ויאמר of 6:1 which very subtly changes the meaning (probably not enough to invalidate the reading, but still).  If it's a telisha gedola Achashveirosh said "bring... uh... how about the chronicles book.".  If it's a revii we don't see the indecision.

Comment: @heshy I don't follow how a telisha would imply that or make sense grammatically at all. A revii is the way to go.

Comment: @DoubleAA how does it make less sense than hundreds of other examples, for example the zakeif in the first pasuk of this week's parsha?  Whenever there's a bigger mafsik in the middle of the speech than at the beginning, I always interpret it as the first part is the primary part of the speech, and the rest is secondary details.

Comment: @Heshy Huh?  וַיֹּ֤אמֶר יְהוָה֙ אֶל־אַבְרָ֔ם What's wrong with that? In the Esther case you'd be splitting between ספר הזכרונות and דברי הימים which clearly go together. In any event the old manuscripts have the Revii as I expected.

Comment: @DoubleAA while I trust your expertise with manuscripts, doesn't אל הארץ אשר אראך clearly go with לך לך the same way?  Or for a more extreme example פרו ורבו with ומלאו את הארץ in Noach?

Answer (score 1):

There's an ongoing dispute as to whose text is most accurate in general -- Koren, or Breuer's "Chorev". The former has a tlisha, the latter does not. So whatever you do, you're in good hands (though someone will complain).

DoubleAA and I seem to agree (mazeltov!) on this one: no tlisha -- which follows Breuer's text.

For whatever it's worth, Breuer's text is a newer work, and it's informed by the Aleppo Codex -- and many believe (though this is also disputed) that Rambam himself followed the Aleppo Codex.

Comment: We don't currently have the Aleppo Codex on Esther, and the various testimonies we do have about what was there in Esther don't discuss this verse.

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought I'd heard R' Shneur Leiman say you can order a Megillas Esther in "conventional" or "Aleppo" styles? Anyhow, thank you; I just meant that Breuer's Tanach text in general claims to be informed by the Keter Aram Tzova.

Comment: There are about a dozen "conventional" styles for Esther that were in use for the last 200 years (and scores more in the last 1000 years). Since the _Keset HaSofer_ became popular it's down to about 3-4, but anyone who thinks there's some long unbroken tradition behind their "conventional" Esther is kidding themselves. It's just not remotely comparable to the traditions for writing Torahs. But that's a topic for another post...

Comment: We do have some info about what Aleppo said in Esther from testimonies, as I mentioned, but nothing on this verse in particular.

Comment: @DoubleAA  Style here refers to the separation of parshios, Pesuchot or Stumot. The conventional follow the Ram"a which is different from the Codex.

Comment: @lionscribe I am indeed referring mostly to parsha breaks, but no, we have no idea where the Rama's parsha breaks were that you can assert who follows his list. As I said there have been about a dozen parsha lists in use over the last 200 years, and many more in the 450 years since the Rama lived, none of which bore his signature.